# Collapsible panel and space filling

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a div which contains three more divs. The first one is a toolbar that can be collapsed (red in the example). It has a fixed height. The second one (black) has to fill all the remaining space, and must expand if the red one is collapsed. The third one (green) is in fact a button attached to the bottom of the red div. When the user clicks on it, it collapses or expands the red div.

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="tools">
  </div>
  <div id="hider">
  </div>
  <div id="work-area">
  </div>
</div>
```

I made an example on jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/gpoa8s92/3/

I don't see how to make the black div take all the remaining space. I tried using a flexbox, and it works, but the green div isn't attached to the bottom of the red div anymore.

Is there a solution using ass less javascript as possible ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your solution can be achieved with flexbox, just put tools and work area as siblings and for first set static `height`, `flex-grow: 0` and flex `shrink: 0`, and for work area set `height: 100%`, `flex-grow: 1` and flex `shrink: 1`.
This will make tools to occupy 100px and work area remaining place.

Since the toggle button is part of tools you can put it inside it, and move it outside using `position: absolute` and `top: 100%`, and give tools `position: relative` to stick toggle button to its bottom.

Now you can create a class for tools that set its `height: 0` and animate it with CSS transitions.

Then on toggle button click, you can toggle a class on tools and it should be as you wanted.

Toggling tools height could be done without javascript- it would be a bit confusing but more accessible, here's an example of that: https://codepen.io/morganfeeney/pen/KiBty

Prepared an example for you - I've used BEM methodology for naming elements and cached used elements as variables.

```js
const $toggleButton = $('.js-tools-toggle');
const $toggleContent = $('.js-tools-root');
const collapsedClass = 'tools--collapsed';
$toggleButton.on('click', function() {
  $toggleContent.toggleClass(collapsedClass);
})
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.tools {
  transition: height 250ms ease-in-out;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100px;
}

.tools--collapsed {
  height: 0px;
}

.tools__content {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: green;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.tools__action {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  height: 20px;
  background-color: red;
}

.work-area {
  background-color: black;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  height: 100%;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="tools js-tools-root">
    <div class="tools__content"> Content of tools</div>
    <div class="tools__action js-tools-toggle">
    toggle
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="work-area">
    content of work area
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works great ! I just have to adjust that with what I already done

Comment: @Thorkal if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.